# Usage of "this" in the argument of RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.sumant.myapplication2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout myLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
        Button myButton =new Button(this);
        myLayout.addView(myButton);
        setContentView(myLayout);

    }
}
```

The "this" variable is as a reference for the current object. But I am not getting as to why it has been used as a parameter in the above piece of code. I am able to decipher that maybe the constructor of `RelativeLayout` class might be parameterized and we are passing it an object of the same class to initialize the `RelativeLayout` object. Can someone please elaborate it to me.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` requires a `Context` as the constructor argument in your usecase, seeing as `AppCompatActivity` IS A `Context` (inheritance) and your `MainActivity` extends this class then the parameter is satisfied. Full inheritance of `AppCompatActivity` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

In java  "this" variable is as a reference for the current object.

```
RelativeLayout myLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
```

but android these case its constructor parameters it refers the context of activity/fragment

Comment: could you please explain a bit more as to what referring to the context of activity means

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#RelativeLayout(android.content.Context)) method, `public RelativeLayout (Context context)` which takes [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) as a parameter.

To Understand What is 'Context' on Android? visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)